# How do you grab tokens in request headers using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

In the request headers when logging in, there's a header called "cookie" that changes every time, how would I grab that each time and put it in the headers using python requests?

[screenshot of network tab in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYclE.png)

Heres my code:

```
import requests
import time

proxies = {
    "http": "http://us.proxiware.com:2000"
}
login_data =  {'op':'login-main', 'user':'UpbeatPark', 'passwd':'Testingreddit123', 'api_type':'json'}
comment_data = {'thing_id':'t3_gluktj', 'text':'epical. redditor', 'id':'#form-t3_gluktjbx2', 'r':'gaming','renderstyle':'html'}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/82.0.4085.6 Safari/537.36'})
r = s.get('https://old.reddit.com/', proxies=proxies)
time.sleep(2)
r = s.post('https://old.reddit.com/api/login/UpbeatPark', proxies=proxies, data=login_data)
print(r.text)
```

here's the output (I know for a fact it is the correct password):

```
{"json": {"errors": [["WRONG_PASSWORD", "wrong password", "passwd"]]}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's an API endpoint? I don't see it in the documentation: https://reddit.com/dev/api/

Comment: I'm not looking to use the official reddit API

Comment: The cookies should get stored in your session, you can see them with: `print(s.cookies.get_dict())`, what is the output?

Comment: for the get request, `{'csv': '1', 'edgebucket': '0Pqw9yPK6on5Le16al', 'loid': '00000000006ijqnllb.2.1589845020612.superlongstringoftext', 'session_tracker': 'hpXiLhaLq8MrWESMHk.0.1589845020612.superlongstringoftext'} for the post request: `{'csv': '1', 'edgebucket': '0Pqw9yPK6on5Le16al', 'loid': '00000000006ijqnllb.2.1589845020612.superlongstringoftext', 'session_tracker': 'hpXiLhaLq8MrWESMHk.0.1589845023845.superlongstringoftext'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```py
import requests

login_data = {
    "op": "login-main",
    "user": "USER",
    "passwd": "PASS",
    "api_type": "json",
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/82.0.4085.6 Safari/537.36",
}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post("https://old.reddit.com/api/login/USER", headers=headers, data=login_data)

print(r.text)
```

It seems exactly like the code you are using but without proxy. Can you try to turn it off? The proxy might block cookies.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll do some more testing and hopefully get proxies working, but yeah that works fine for me as well!

Edit: works completely fine with proxies lol, I guess sending a get request to old.reddit.com wasn't a good idea